# Get rid of Division by 0 error with Excel-Writer-XLSX

Tags: perl

Is there any with with Excel-Writer-XLSX module where we can get rid of "Division by 0" error which looks like "#DIV/0!" in excel sheet.

I am creating table with add_table method of Excel-Writer-XLSX module by getting data dynamically. It divides A with B to show percentage count. But if B is 0, it shows "#DIV/0!" in excel sheet.

I am not able to find any method there in the documentation. Please help me with this.

Comment: Isn't there a function in excel like IF or CASE or...? Where you can do one thing if the denominator is 0 and the division otherwise.

Comment: I dint find any. The thing is we are adding data dynamically to the table. You have to just provide the column names and type and of course data array.

Comment: This isn't a general or known issue with Excel::Writer::XLXS. It is something specific to your program so can you post some sample code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sorry jmcnamara....Earlier I thought that there is limitation with the Perl module only as I am not that great in Excel processing. But Now It's working fine after modifying the formula in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter your formula for the column/field that shows the `#DIV/0` error. It probably has something like this:

```
=A1/B1
```

Now you just need to change it to:

```
=IF(B1<>0;A1/B1;"")
```

That will make it an empty string if you try do divide by zero.

In Excel::Writer::XLSX that would look like this:

```
$worksheet->write( 'C1', '=IF(B1<>0;A1/B1;"")' );
```